# SQL - illegal character in XML parsing trying to add replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I add a replace function to this code :

```
cast (convert(varchar(max), Convert(varbinary(max), c_xml)) as xml) c_xml
```

I get an xml parsing error. I believe I would need to conver & to &amp. I found one of the cell in sql where the problem lies to have two box like characters.

```
<SyncShipment xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.6.3" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2 http://schema.infor.com/trunk/InforOAGIS/BODs/Developer/SyncShipment.xsd"><ApplicationArea><Sender><LogicalID>infor.syteline.tangent</LogicalID><ComponentID>erp</ComponentID></Sender><CreationDateTime>2018-09-13T19:02:40Z</CreationDateTime><BODID>infor-nid:infor:Tangent:Tangent:5222898:?Shipment&amp;verb=Sync</BODID></ApplicationArea><DataArea><Sync><TenantID>infor</TenantID><AccountingEntityID>Tangent</AccountingEntityID><LocationID>Tangent~MAIN</LocationID><ActionCriteria><ActionExpression actionCode="Add" /></ActionCriteria></Sync><Shipment><ShipmentHeader><DocumentID><ID accountingEntity="Tangent" lid="infor.syteline.tangent" location="Tangent~MAIN" variationID="2745613608842789">5222898</ID></DocumentID><DisplayID>5222898</DisplayID><LastModificationDateTime>2018-09-13T19:02:28Z</LastModificationDateTime><DocumentDateTime>2018-09-13T19:02:28Z</DocumentDateTime><Status><Code listID="Shipment Status">Shipped</Code><EffectiveDateTime>2018-09-13T19:02:28Z</EffectiveDateTime></Status><WarehouseLocation><ID accountingEntity="Tangent" location="Tangent">Tangent~MAIN</ID><Name languageID="en-US">Tangent Technologies</Name><Address><AddressLine sequence="1">1001 Sullivan Road</AddressLine><AddressLine sequence="2" /><AddressLine sequence="3" /><AddressLine sequence="4" /><CityName>Aurora</CityName><CountrySubDivisionCode listID="State-Province">IL</CountrySubDivisionCode><CountryCode listID="Countries">US</CountryCode><PostalCode listID="Postal/ZIP Codes">60506</PostalCode></Address></WarehouseLocation><ActualShipDateTime>2018-09-13T19:02:28Z</ActualShipDateTime><ActualDeliveryDateTime>2018-09-13T19:02:28Z</ActualDeliveryDateTime><ShipFromParty><PartyIDs><ID accountingEntity="Tangent">Tangent</ID></PartyIDs><Name>Tangent Technologies</Name><Location><ID accountingEntity="Tangent" location="Tangent">Tangent~MAIN</ID><Name languageID="en-US">Tangent Technologies</Name><Address><AddressLine sequence="1">1001 Sullivan Road</AddressLine><AddressLine sequence="2" /><AddressLine sequence="3" /><AddressLine sequence="4" /><CityName>Aurora</CityName><CountrySubDivisionCode listID="State-Province">IL</CountrySubDivisionCode><CountryCode listID="Countries">US</CountryCode><PostalCode listID="Postal/ZIP Codes">60506</PostalCode></Address></Location></ShipFromParty><CarrierParty><PartyIDs><ID accountingEntity="Tangent" /></PartyIDs><Location><ID /></Location></CarrierParty><ShipToParty><PartyIDs><ID accountingEntity="Tangent">Tangent~MAIN</ID></PartyIDs><Name>Tangent Technologies</Name><Location><ID accountingEntity="Tangent" location="Tangent">Tangent~MAIN</ID><Name languageID="en-US">Tangent Technologies</Name><Address><AddressLine sequence="1">1001 Sullivan Road</AddressLine><AddressLine sequence="2" /><AddressLine sequence="3" /><AddressLine sequence="4" /><CityName>Aurora</CityName><CountrySubDivisionCode listID="State-Province">IL</CountrySubDivisionCode><CountryCode listID="Countries">US</CountryCode><PostalCode listID="Postal/ZIP Codes">60506</PostalCode></Address></Location><Contact><Communication><UseCode listID="Communication Use Codes">Phone</UseCode><DialNumber>630-264-1110</DialNumber></Communication></Contact></ShipToParty><CustomerParty><Name languageID="en-US">Tangent Technologies</Name><Location><Name languageID="en-US">Tangent Technologies</Name><Address><AddressLine sequence="1">1001 Sullivan Road</AddressLine><CityName>Aurora</CityName><CountrySubDivisionCode listID="State-Province">IL</CountrySubDivisionCode><CountryCode listID="Countries">US</CountryCode><PostalCode listID="Postal/ZIP Codes">60506</PostalCode></Address></Location><Contact><Communication><UseCode listID="Communication Use Codes">phone</UseCode></Communication></Contact></CustomerParty></ShipmentHeader><ShipmentItem><ItemID><ID accountingEntity="Tangent">.75X2.625X144XMCHXR187X2E2</ID></ItemID><Description>3/4 x 2 5/8 x 144 Mocha DEM 2PAT</Description><OrderQuantity unitCode="">240.00000000</OrderQuantity><ShippedQuantity unitCode="">240.00000000</ShippedQuantity><ShippedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="">240.00000000</ShippedBaseUOMQuantity><EstimatedWeightMeasure unitCode="">1756.8000000000000</EstimatedWeightMeasure><LoadingWeightMeasure unitCode="">1756.8000000000000</LoadingWeightMeasure><PlannedShipQuantity unitCode="">240.00000000</PlannedShipQuantity><SerializedLot><Lot sequence="1"><LotIDs><ID accountingEntity="Tangent">.75X2.625X144XMCHXR187X2E2~33191-02-01</ID></LotIDs></Lot></SerializedLot><LineNumber>10</LineNumber><CountSequence>1</CountSequence></ShipmentItem></Shipment></DataArea></SyncShipment>
```

This is one of the parsing that went through. Every few minutes batches like these go through.

This has to be converted to XML : `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`

Comment: Can you provide us with the XML ?

Comment: added the xml that actually converts

Comment: What about the one that doesn't convert and actually throw the error?

Comment: added the message, i really couldnt find a illegal character here

Comment: How is this supposed to be converted to XML?

Comment: @PaulKaram, well, the binaries is nothing else than a `varchar(max)`. The problem is, that the resulting string xml contains bad characters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this position your XML includes bad characters (shortend with `...`):

```
<ID lid="..." schemeAgencyID="..." schemeName="...">1124-8TURFGR&#x4;&#x1;</ID>
```

Taking the `&#x4;&#x1;` away resolves the problem.

But: These two characters are part of the `<ID>`s value. I do not know, why these characters are there, neither do I know if they have any meaning.

'#x4' is known as *end-of-transmission*, while '#x1' is known as *start-of-heading*. I'm pretty sure, that these invisible characters are some kind of residue...

Try it out:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@xmlBin AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'&#x4;&#x1;','') AS XML)
```

Comment: I was able to remove the special characters and it fixed it. Thanks so much. Now how did you convert the binary to xml?

Comment: @raider my last line is exactly doing this. After casting the binaries to a string you can cast this string to xml

Comment: Remove the special characters fixed the issue and this binary converted to xml and went through but the query gives me an error message saying ‘explicit conversion from data type image to  varchar(max) is not allowed

Comment: @raider Image is deprecated for centuries! Get rid of it... You'll need three casts: varbinary(max) - varchar(max) - xml